# How do I parse log4j %M (method name) field using grok pattern?

Tags: logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

Below is my scenario:

Unable to get Request-ID "9bb0c7bcf81425fd6773" parsed into field Request-ID?

**Sample message:**

```
05/11/2016 10:55:43.167|INFO|com.abc.requestidgenerator.Tester$.main(UniqueIDGenerator.scala:95)|9bb0c7bcf81425fd6773|This is Debug Message
```

**Grok pattern:**

```
match => { "message" => "%{DATESTAMP:Date-Time}\|%{LOGLEVEL:Level}%{SPACE}\|%{NOTSPACE:Method}\|%{USERNAME:Request-ID}"}
```

**Grokpattern output**

```
{
            "@timestamp" => "2016-05-12T11:44:55.100Z",
               "message" => "05/11/2016 10:55:43.167|INFO |com.abc.requestidgenerator.Tester$.main(UniqueIDGenerator.scala:95)|9bb0c7bcf81425fd6773|This is Debug Message...",
             "Date-Time" => "05/11/2016 10:55:43.167",
                 "Level" => "INFO",
                "Method" => "com.abc.requestidgenerator.Tester$.main(UniqueIDGenerator.scala:95)|9bb0c7bcf81425fd6773",
            "Request-ID" => "This",
        "ALCH_TENANT_ID" => "da5109ef-c1c0-499b-86ee-a8fd55203bb6"
}
```

Comment: you seem to have a different grok pattern than you posted, I don't see `ALCH_TENANT_ID` in the pattern

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `NOTSPACE` use `DATA`. `NOTSPACE` is trying to capture everything up to a space, but there are no spaces until your message. `DATA` will lazy capture as few newline characters as possible without breaking the regex.

`...\|%{DATA:Method}\|...`